# Script could not be transmitted

Tags: pine-script

I was up  4 hours pass my bedtime trying to write a &^%$  pine script and I keep getting an error. I am absolutley sure I am close  but I keep getting a ID-10T error (idiot).  Below is the script I wrote and the image reflects the error.

```
//  Kadinim 20/50ema strategy
ema20 = ema(close, 20)
ema50 = ema(close, 50)

long = ema20 > ema50
short = ema50 < ema20

start = timestamp(GMT-5, 2023, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
end = timestamp(GMT-5, 2023, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1)

If time >= start and time >= end
strategy.entry("long", strategy.long,100,when = long)
strategy.entry("short", strategy.short,100,when = short)
Strategy.close("short", when = long)
strategy.close("long", when = short)
```

I visited the line of code it seemed to be directting me to ("If time > ...) and I looked t logic, then assumed it was a typo I am missing so i rewrote it 10X. all to no avail.
Not seeing my error.

Program Purpsoe: The programming simply executes buys and sells as the 20 and 50 ema cross each other.  It also allows me to specifcy the period of samplig.

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues with this code.

1. Pinescript is case-sensitive. So, `If` and `Strategy` will cause a compiler error. It should be `if` and `strategy`.
2. Your if block must be indented by 4 spaces.
3. The timezone argument in `timestamp()` is of type `string`.

This will fix it:

```
start = timestamp("GMT-5", 2023, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
end = timestamp("GMT-5", 2023, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1)

if time >= start and time >= end
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long,100,when = long)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short,100,when = short)
    strategy.close("short", when = long)
    strategy.close("long", when = short)
```

Comment: Thank  you Vitruvious. Alll errors gone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

You should use crossover/crossunder instead of ema20>ema50, because "ema20>ema50" condition passed in all candles while the next cross occurred, you want to open a position at the ema cross moment.

Furthermore, I added Start/End time values as "input.time" to have more flexibility.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

backtestStartDate = input.time(timestamp("1 Nov 2023"),title="Start Date", group="Backtest Time Period")
backtestEndDate   = input.time(timestamp("28 Nov 2023"),title="End Date", group="Backtest Time Period")

ema20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

// Conditions for sell signal
sellCondition = ta.crossunder(ema20, ema50)
// Conditions for buy signal
buyCondition = ta.crossover(ema20, ema50) 

// Plot EMAs on the chart for visual reference
plot(ema20, color = color.blue, title = "EMA5")
plot(ema50, color = color.red, title = "EMA21")

time_period_condition = time >= backtestStartDate and time <= backtestEndDate

if (buyCondition) and time_period_condition
    strategy.close("sell", qty_percent = 100, comment = "Close previous Short Position")
    strategy.entry("Open a New Long Position", strategy.long)

if (sellCondition) and time_period_condition
    strategy.close("buy", qty_percent = 100, comment = "Close previous Long Position")
    strategy.entry("Open a New Short Position", strategy.short)
```

I tested it before share with you and you can see the result in below picture:

[image: Result]

Comment: Arman thnk u so much. Your program was excellent. I can see the ema20>ema50 issue you referenced, it resulted in infinite executions. u were right

But I have a question regarding ur progrm. i dont see ont eh chart where the STOPs/ Exits are executed. Only see the entires. HOw can I see the exits on the charts also? good program.

thx in advance

Comment: you're welcome dear, at the moment you don't have any exit condition in your strategy, so by coming a new opposite signal, previous position will close, I know it's not perffesional but you can easily add a close condition or TP/SL in your strategy and enjoy.